# How to get more details regarding Python "the specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, python-2.7

When importing a DLL module into Python, sometimes I will get:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The problem is often:

- Missing DLL dependency (commonly a Visual Studio runtime DLL)
- DLL or dependency compiled for 32 bit when should be 64 bit

Dependency walker answers this question sometimes. But, sometimes it doesn't, particularly if the issue is a missing Visual Studio runtime DLL.

Is there a way to make Python tell me the name of the missing DLL dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.

I was unable to solve my problem using Python alone. So I used C++ instead.

I made a small win32 application to link with the `.lib` file produced alongside the `.pyd` file, and forced it to use a symbol from the `.pyd` file:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void initmymodule();
```

...

```
printf("%p\n", initmymodule);
```

Then, when running this program, Windows would tell me which DLL was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Run the script_name.py from the shell, (cmd.exe or powershell in Windows) and read the error message(s). The error will show which dependency is missing.

You may need to repeat this process several times, if you are missing more than one.

Any IDE, including IDLE will display an error message in a window, buried in the error message is the name of the missing file.